# Infinite scroll display something between range

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I display something when my infinite scroll between range?

For an Example : I want to display my Ads when infinite scroll feed by 3 range.

```
1 TEXT1
2 TEXT2
3 TEXT3

Ads //Added when it's feed by 3 range.

4 TEXT4
5 TEXT5
6 TEXT6

Ads //Added when it's feed by 3 range.

...(Repeat until finish)
```

**scroll.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['actionfunction']) && $_REQUEST['actionfunction']!=''){
$actionfunction = $_REQUEST['actionfunction'];

 call_user_func($actionfunction,$_REQUEST,$con,$limit);
}
function showData($data,$con,$limit){
 $page = $data['page'];
 if($page==1){
 $start = 0;
 }
 else{
 $start = ($page-1)*$limit;
 }

 $sql = "select * from infinitescroll order by id asc limit $start,$limit";
 $str='';
 $data = $con->query($sql);
 if($data!=null && $data->num_rows>0){
 while( $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 $str.="<div class='data-container'><p>".$row['id']."</p><p>".$row['firstname']."</p><p>".$row['lastname']."</p></div>";
 }
 $str.="<input type='hidden' class='nextpage' value='".($page+1)."'><input type='hidden' class='isload' value='true'>";
 }else{
 $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='isload' value='false'><p>Finished</p>";
 }
echo $str;
}
?>
```

**scroll.js**

```
 var ajax_arry=[];
 var ajax_index =0;
 var sctp = 100;
 $(function(){
 $('#loading').show();
 $.ajax({
 url:"scroll.php",
 type:"POST",
 data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
 cache: false,
 success: function(response){
 $('#loading').hide();
 $('#demoajax').html(response);

 }

 });
 $(window).scroll(function(){

 var height = $('#demoajax').height();
 var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(ajax_arry.length>0){
 $('#loading').hide();
 for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
 ajax_arry[i].abort();
 }
 }
 var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
 var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

 if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)==$(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
 $('#loading').show();
 var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
 url:"scroll.php",
 type:"POST",
 data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
 cache: false,
 success: function(response){
 $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
 $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
 $('#loading').hide();

 $('#demoajax').append(response);

 }

 });
 ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;

 }
 return false;

 if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
 alert("bottom!");
 }
 });

});
```

Here's example live [Demo](http://www.infotuts.com/demo/infinite-scroll-jquery/) from original site.

Comment: Aside from many things that irk me, `call_user_func($actionfunction,$_REQUEST,$con,$limit)` stands out as very alarming. I recommend removing that asap

Comment: @Isaac Why should I remove that?

Comment: It calls any function on `actionfunction=` in the url. I'm trying to figure out if I can put my own code in there, but for now try `actionfunction=var_dump`

Comment: @Isaac Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: @Issac I've put it on `data:"actionfunction=var_dump"` and `data:"actionfunction=var_dump"+page` Am I right?

Comment: Ok, I have identified the vulnerability. If the user has any access to the `$con` variable, then you have trouble. Eg: `$con = 'print_r("i am in your system");'` and the user requests `/dodgy.php?0=/(.*)/e&actionfunction=preg_replace` you may be able to see that the code defined in $con is executed, thus anything goes. Always be careful with user input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104701/discussion-between-vintage-beef-and-isaac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keep track of an index alongside your data fetching

```
$index = 0; 
while( $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
//... your other code 
if($index++%3==2){ 
$str.="ad stuff"; 
} 

}
```